# select value not getting passed

Tags: php, select, image-uploading

can some one please tell me why its not getting passsed. all the other value gets passed except for the select option value. the files gets updates perfectly as i want. but the album ID doesnt get assigned as i want :( .

HTML Code from the page:

```
    <form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >                          
    <label>Select Image:</label>
    <input type="file" aria-required="true" size="30" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <?php if(isset($_GET['al'])){ ?>
    <label>Album(required):</label>                                                                             
    <select name='album'  id='album' aria-required="true">     
    <?php 
    $query_album = "SELECT * FROM  `albums` ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
    $result_m = $conn->query($query_album);
    if ($result_m->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($item_a = $result_m->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $value= $item_a['id'];?>
            <option value='<?php echo $value; ?>'>
            <?php echo $item_a['title']; ?>
            </option>    
       <?php 
       }
    } ?>                                
    </select>
  <?php } ?>
  <label>Image Title :</label>
  <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name='title' id='title'>    
  <label> Image Description :</label>
  <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name='desc' id='desc'>    
  <button type="submit" value="Upload!" class="soc-icon soc-icon-small soc-icon-alt fa fa-floppy-o">    
  </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="reset" name="reset" class="soc-icon soc-icon-small soc-icon-alt fa fa-refresh">
  </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
  <input type="hidden" name="album" id="album" value="<?php echo $album; ?>"> 
  <a href="gallery.php" class="soc-icon soc-icon-small soc-icon-alt fa fa-arrow-left"></a>
  </form>
```

PHP Code from the UPLOAD PAGE where the values are passed to... all other values gets passed except for the album id. can some one please help me to figure out what i'm doin wrong.

```
  <?php
  include 'DBConfig.php';
  require 'imageconfig.php';
  require 'img_functions.php';
  if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
     if(!empty($_POST['album'])){
        $album_id = $_POST['album'];
        $image_title=$_POST['title'];   
        $image_desc=$_POST['desc']; 
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];                
            if($file_size > 2097152){
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }       
            $query="INSERT into images(`ID`,`ALBUM_ID`,`CAPTION`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`,`DESC`) VALUES(DEFAULT,'{$album_id}','$image_title','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type','$image_desc'); ";
            $desired_dir="uploads/fullsized/";
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                        mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/fullsized/".$file_name);                      
                create_square_image("uploads/fullsized/".$file_name,"uploads/thumbs/".$file_name,200);                  
                }
                else{           //rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="uploads/fullsized/".$file_name.time();
                    rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;                
                }
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);              
            }else{
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }
        if(empty($error)){
            header('Location:gallery.php');
        }
    }
    else { 
        echo"album id not set";
    } 
 }    ?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmmm, am I missing a duplicate somewhere?

Comment: @jeroen what I meant by that was, that I've seen this exact same piece of code a few times in the past week but from different users.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I must be too busy, I'm pretty sure I would have remembered something like this :-)

Comment: @jeroen code's like a fingerprint/face for me. I never forget a face ;-)

Comment: i've been using this same snippet for years.... :)  didnt take from any where any time recently. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your input with another one with the same name:

```
<select name='album'  id='album' aria-required="true">
...
<input type="hidden" name="album" id="album" value="<?php echo $album; ?>">
```

Comment: awsome.. thanks a lot. you always need someone else to figure out the mistakes. been looking at this for weeks now i couldnt see that.